# Turing Machine calculator

Tags: automata, turing-machines

Can someone give me a code of example for Turing Machine Calculator

which can accept these inputs

```
30+25x3-2/5=
```

and the output is 104.6

this calculator cant accept these input

```
3+52-2
43+1=12
0+12+1=
2+0+x2=
1x02=
+2+3=
x19x1=
12x2x=
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a homework assignment, so I won't give you the code, but in general what you'll need to do is parse the input into a tree structure based on order of operations, and then resolve it recursively. There are several ways to achieve this but it is likely, if this is a homework assignment, that your professor has recently talked about the specific way he or she would like you to solve it.

You will essentially be reimplementing the *nix "bc" program. The GNU implementation is free software, and you can get the code to inspect here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/